# SQLite Transform Columns to Comma Delimited String

Tags: android, sqlite, concatenation, transpose, delimited

I have a table with rows of data and need to create a comma delimited string for all the rows for a column.  Can this be achieved just using the the SELECT statement in SQLite or I have to get the data into Cursor and build the string by iterating through it?

For Example:

```
UserId
1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c70
1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c71
1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c72
1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c73
1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c74
1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c75
```

into

```
1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c70,1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c71,1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c72,1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c73,1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c74,1df4181d-6c52-4aa3-926f-2dacb0a68c75
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html):

```
select group_concat(yourColumn, ',')
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2f79d/1)